# How can I insert a variable from the React context API into a placeholder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, placeholder

I'm using the React Context API to display my site in multiple languages. Everything works as it should apart from when I try and insert a placeholder in my text area,  It displays `[object Object]`. If I use the same component in my actual for example in

tags it displays correctly!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Translate from '../translations/Translate'

class FormEntry extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="inputArea shadow">
        <textarea
          className="dataInputChild"
          placeholder={<Translate string={'submitbox.copy-and-paste'}/>}//this displays [object Object]
        />
        <p><Translate string={'submitbox.copy-and-paste'}/></p> //this displays the desired text
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default FormEntry;
```

The Translate Component is as follows:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import en from "./en.json";
import es from "./es.json"; //these are the dictionary files
import cn from "./cn.json";
LanguageContext = React.createContext()

export default class Translate extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      langs: {
        en,
        es,
        cn
      }
    };
  }
  render() {
      const {langs} = this.state 
      const {string} = this.props
    return (
      <LanguageContext.Consumer>
        {value => langs[value][string]}
      </LanguageContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand on [Estus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54491979/8331783), just create a separate function which accepts the languages, the language value and the string (like you do in the `Translate` component in the `render` method) and reuse it everywhere you need.

You'll separate the context from the actual functionality and you can reuse the function like this: 
(or in any other other components where you have access to the context).

```
// langs -> coming from context or some map of languages you use
// langValue -> coming from the context API
// 'submitbox.copy-and-paste' -> the actual string you want to translate

const translation = translate(langs, langValue, 'submitbox.copy-and-paste');
// and then use the variable in as placeholder and the <p> tag
// or if different string values see below

<div className="inputArea shadow">
   <textarea 
      className="dataInputChild" 
      placeholder={translate(langs, langValue, 'submitbox.copy-and-paste')}
   />
   <p>{translate(langs, langValue, 'submitbox.copy-and-paste')}/></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Translate string={'submitbox.copy-and-paste'}/>` is React element, which is an object. It cannot be provided as `placeholder` attribute because a string is expected.

`FormEntry` component can use [`contextType`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype) to have access to the context. This limits the component to use a single context.